# convert session to int for linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, session

I am trying to take number of variables from my database with a where condition but I get an error like

> 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   Parse(System.String)' method'.

Here is my code:

```
var tickets = (from a in user.TicketTable where a.HandlerId == int.Parse(Session["emp"].ToString()) && a.Done == true select a.TicketId);
int count = 0;
foreach (var n in tickets) 
{
 count++;
}
lblDone.Text = count.ToString();
```

I tried other methods to convert my session to int but they all gave the same result.

Comment: Sidenote: if you stored that "emp" value as int, then you just need to cast Session["emp"] to int. No need to first convert to string only to convert it back to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to move the parse outside of the Linq to Entities query, e.g.

```
var emp =int.Parse(Session["emp"].ToString()) ;
var tickets = (from a in user.TicketTable where a.HandlerId == emp &&
 a.Done == true select a.TicketId);
```

Answer (score 1):

`int.Parse` couldn't be translated to T-SQL, Linq to Entities couldn't recognize it. You can modify the code as below (*Move the parse function out of expression*):

```
int emp = int.Parse(Session["emp"].ToString());

var tickets = (from a in user.TicketTable where a.HandlerId == emp &&
                a.Done == true 
                select a.TicketId);
```

Also Have a look at this link may useful : [`How to resolve: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method int.Parse.`](http://www.toplinestrategies.com/blogs/net/how-resolve-linq-entities-does-not-recognize-method-intparse/blog-page)